# How to handle multiple categories of ordinal data for clustering?

Tags: machine-learning, data-cleaning

I wanted to ask about how multiple categories of ordinal data handled for the purposed of running some clustering.

For instance, I have survey data where respondents answer the following questions:

a. How happy are you with your life?

Choose: depressed, meh, not bad, happy

b. Do you think your mother loves your sibling more than yourself?

Choose: loves them more, about the same, loves me more.

Each single variable is ordinal, where the outcome gets better as the response is higher, so within a variable there is a hierarchy. So sklearn's Ordinal encoder, for example, will assign them 0,1,2,3 and 0,1,2.

That's ok I suppose within a single survey question, but across questions it doesn't make any sense.

The "distance" between a response of (depressed, loves them more) i.e. (0,0) and (meh, about the same) i.e. (1,1) is the same as the distance between the response (meh, about the same) i.e. (1,1) and (not bad, loves me more) i.e. (2,2)

That would change if I encode question b. as 0 = loves them more, 1 = about the same, and 5 = loves me more. Because now the three numbers become (0,0) , (1,1) , (2,5).

The theory about "well being" doesn't tell me how to compare across different questions and doesn't tell me how much more happy someone is if their life improves by one category in question a. vs question b.

Maybe (0,1,2,3) and (0,1,2) encoding captures reality or maybe (0,1,2,3) and (0,1,5) encoding captures reality. I don't know.

How is this handled in practice? What are different ways of approaching this if there isn't one canonical/correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handling ordinal data for clustering can be tricky due to the reasons you mentioned. Here are a few approaches that you may try:

**Ordinal Encoding**: As you mentioned, you can use ordinal encoding, where you assign an integer to each category. The problem with this approach is that the distances between categories may not be equal, and this method assumes they are.

**One-Hot Encoding**: This method creates a new binary column for each category. This can result in numerous columns if you have many categories, but it avoids the problem of unequal distances.

**Target Encoding**: This method replaces each category with the mean target value for that category. This can be useful if there is a strong relationship between the category and the target, but it can lead to overfitting.

**Custom Encoding**: If you have domain knowledge that suggests a certain ordering or distance between categories, you can use this to create a custom encoding.

**Embedding**: This involves training a neural network to learn a dense representation of the categories. This can capture complex relationships but requires more computational resources.

In your case, since you don't know the true distances between categories, you might want to try a few different methods and see which one works best for your specific problem. You could also consider using a non-parametric clustering algorithm that doesn't make assumptions about the distances between categories.

Finally, the goal of clustering is to find meaningful groups in your data. If a certain encoding method leads to clusters that make sense in the context of your problem, then it's probably a good choice.

Comment: thanks so much for your response and guidance. It's very helpful. I'll wait a day to see if anyone else responds before accepting your answer. In the mean time I'll google embedding and start testing all the methods. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to help you!